# Trying to access a server I just built. Every time I try to use ssh in my windows pc I get a timeout on port 22

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have a Linux ubuntu pc which I'm trying to set up as a server. when I put the command into Windows PowerShell it gives me a timeout on port 22 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykZXc.png). It also looks for the ssh config files, which don't exist on my system.

I followed an online tutorial which told me to use the command ssh rudy@192.168.1.51 in PowerShell. the expected outcome was for it to take me to login through PowerShell. The result is in sc

It also seems as though I cant ping the server from my pc, as all of the requests time out

Comment: First you have to resolve the ping problem. Are you sure the network is physically connected OK? Is the networking configured correctly on the Ubuntu machine? No firewall on either side? Once you get the ping working, then you may proceed to trying ssh.

Comment: Yes, check for firewall. Also did you install an SSH server on the Ubuntu PC?

Comment: Providing details of what Ubuntu product (*Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Core [server]? including release details*) usually help us understand your issue. You mention server, but didn't state if you're trying to install Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Core (a *flavor* of Ubuntu Server) or provide any release details.  Defaults can differ between products/releases (*a desktop system doesn't start with `openssh-server` installed*).

Comment: Being unable to ping typically doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu, but rather outside factors.